# How to get today's date in Windows batch environment?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to get today's date in the format of YYYYMMDD in Windows batch environment, but don't know where to start or what to do.

Any code or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On my system, where `echo %date%` returns `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
set now=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
echo.%now%
```

The syntax used is `%date:~S,L%` where `S` is a character offset and `L` is the length to read from the value returned by `%date%`.

Comment: +1 on your answer.  Just curious, what does the dot in `echo.%now%` do?  I know `echo.` writes a blank line, but I've never seen that before.

Comment: Its a trick to prevent ECHO from accidentally running a command; if `%f%` was `"OFF"` then `echo %f%` would **run** the command `"ECHO OFF"` which would disable echoing, the period makes `ECHO.%f%` print `"OFF"`.

Comment: On my Windows 10 box, echo %date% is formatted like: Thu 12/01/2016

Comment: %date% is formatted in the current system format, i.e. german system: 15.01.2017

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
  "wmic path Win32_LocalTime get year,month,day /value|findstr ="
  ') do @set %%a
echo %year%%month%%day%
pause
```

Comment: Extremely underrated answer. However, is it possible to get leading zeros for the month and the day?

Answer (score 2):

You may also use a FOR command to separate the parts of a date:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set now=%%c%%a%%b
```

Date components are split by / (delims) and taken the first three parts (tokens) in variable %%a and successive ones (%%b and %%c).

Although this seems more complicated than the former method, it is less prone to get errors when you used it. For further details, type: `FOR /?`

Answer (score 0):

Rob van Der Woude has a script that [parses the date](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php#Prompt) without using WMIC, which requires administrative rights. Here's the link to the script. Just rename it to a .BAT file:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/sortdate_dos.txt

Comment: Please edit your solution into your answer and then cite the source so that it can be seen at a glance. Also, the script requires BATCHMAN so this isn't a vanilla solution.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 machine, the %date% format is different from the values expected by @Alex K. answer, so it didn't work for me.  After doing some more research, I dug up the following script, which is good for obtaining any date in the format of your choice.  Use `day=0` for today, `day=1` for tomorrow, `day=-1` for yesterday, etc...

```
set day=0
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "today=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"

echo %today%
```

Answer (score 0):

@raider33 's script works, here is another way which use PowerShell:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "Get-Date -uformat '%%Y%%m%%d'"') do (
    set "Today=%%i"
)
echo,%Today%
```